# JS Regex: select only links (a) with attr

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have to select link tag (`a`) with a specific data-attr. Now I'm doing it this way:
`/<a.*?data-extra-url=".*?<\/a>/g`. But... For some reason when my input string is without any line br -> it results in a totally wrong selection, for example:

```
<div> <br> <a data-some-id="3-6-9;id-1-2-3" data-more-id="1-3-5" data-extra-url="https://somehost.api/sub-id-1-2-3?someparam=3-6-9;id-1-2-3" href="https://somehost.api/sub-id-1-2-3?someparam=3-6-9;id-1-2-3" class="some-class">someDuplicateHere1</a></div> wysiwyg<br> <div><a class="popup-wrap-id-1-2-3" href="https://somehost.api/app/id-1-2-3?someparam=sub-id-1-2-3;sub-sub-id-1-2-3">firstImage</a></div> <br> <div>somecontent</div> <div> <span> <div><a data-some-id="456;789" href="https://somehost.api/app/id-4-5-6?someparam=sub-id-4-5-6;sub-sub-1-2-3">second</a></div> <br> </span> also some more content </div> <div> <span> <div><a data-some-id="3-6-9;id-1-2-3" data-more-id="1-3-5" data-extra-url="https://somehost.api/app/sub-id-1-2-3?someparam=3-6-9;id-1-2-3" href="https://somehost.api/app/sub-id-1-2-3?someparam=3-6-9;id-1-2-3" class="some-class">someDuplicateHere</a></div> rtf<br> </span> <br> </div> </div>
```

and a live example: https://regex101.com/r/JkI3Fu/1

for some reasons in my selection there are all links, what I do wrong?

As a result I want to get:

```
array = ['<a data-some-id="3-6-9;id-1-2-3" data-more-id="1-3-5" data-extra-url="https://somehost.api/sub-id-1-2-3?someparam=3-6-9;id-1-2-3" href="https://somehost.api/sub-id-1-2-3?someparam=3-6-9;id-1-2-3" class="some-class">someDuplicateHere1</a>', '<a data-some-id="3-6-9;id-1-2-3" data-more-id="1-3-5" data-extra-url="https://somehost.api/app/sub-id-1-2-3?someparam=3-6-9;id-1-2-3" href="https://somehost.api/app/sub-id-1-2-3?someparam=3-6-9;id-1-2-3" class="some-class">someDuplicateHere</a>']
like here: https://regex101.com/r/NiFFXd/1
```

Comment: [Obligatory link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454). You can't use a simple regex to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser to parse HTML.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it's not acceptable in terms of performance if I will have to use it in a huge html chunks...

Comment: That's unfortunate, but it doesn't change the reality that you can't use a simple regex to parse HTML.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I guess it's not true. Every time you can write a correct regex :)

Comment: what expect output do you want for above data?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not arguing.

Comment: @brabertaser19 look at my answer if you don’t want RegEx

Comment: thanks @RazLuvaton but I can't use dom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important that your regex looks at what you don't want in your match. Use ^ like this

```
<a[^>]*data-extra-url="[^>]*>[^>]*.
```

It should solve your problem

Comment: That's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[data-extra-url]');
```

> The `[attribute]` selector is used to select elements with a specified attribute.
>
> From [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_attribute_selectors.asp)